# Authorizing Requests to the Google Calendar API only once time in Java

Tags: java, api, google-calendar-api

I was looking in google calendar in Java API and got confused.

My problem is this: When I run my application it generates a URL that when I put it in the browser generates a code. I was wondering how to do the next time I will be running the application does not need this url to generate the code, I wonder if it is possible to make these steps only once!

Here's the code:

```
public void setUp() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {

            HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            JacksonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

             // The clientId and clientSecret can be found in Google Developers Console


                String clientSecret = "0XgfTEYxDjTyQITWHd6YtxnT";

                // Or your redirect URL for web based applications.

                String redirectUrl = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
                String scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar";

                GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(
                    httpTransport, jsonFactory, CLIENT_ID, clientSecret, Collections.singleton(scope));

                // Step 1: Authorize
                String authorizationUrl = flow.newAuthorizationUrl().setRedirectUri(redirectUrl).build();


                // Point or redirect your user to the authorizationUrl.

                    System.out.println("Go to the following link in your browser:");
                    System.out.println(authorizationUrl);


                // Read the authorization code from the standard input stream.

                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                    System.out.println("What is the authorization code?");
                    String code = in.readLine();

                    // End of Step 1

                    // Step 2: Exchange

                    GoogleTokenResponse response = flow.newTokenRequest(code).setRedirectUri(redirectUrl)
                        .execute();

                     // End of Step 2
                    Credential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setTransport(httpTransport).setJsonFactory(jsonFactory).setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID, clientSecret)
                    .build().setFromTokenResponse(response);


                    service = new Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName("YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME").build();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The flow is like this

1. You send the client id / secret and get a url for authentication.
2. Using url you authenticate yourself and get a code.
3. You exchange the code with access_token.
4. This access token can be used with the api for a specific time ( usually 1 hour )

So you can generate an access_tone once and can use it for an hour instead of generating it again and again.

```
static {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
      public void run() {
        synchronized(Singleton.class) {
          access_token = new MethodToInitializeAccessToken();
        }
      }
    }, 60 * 60 * 1000L /* Once per hour */);
  }
```

Comment: I understood what you said! In my code, just have to verify if credential is null ? That's it?

Comment: Credential may not become null after an hour , You will actually need a mechanism to refresh Credential after every hour.

Comment: I have little experience in programming in java and is also the first time I am using the google calendar API, so I am with many difficulties. You know how this mechanism refresh or where I can find some example?

Comment: I think you should be good even with generating new code and access token everytime. Are you facing any trouble by generating token multiple times and then using a new token with each request.

Comment: I have added the code to call and initialize the method every one hour.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I'm trying to understand how and where in your code enter the mine!